# Exporting/Defining Static Template Specialized Member Variable C++

Tags: c++, templates

So I am currently exporting a DLL, and I've run into a problem where I have a template class that contains a static char*[] member variable. I want to define this for specializations of that template.

example:

MyTemplate.h

```
#include <dll_defines.h>

template <typename T>
class MY_API MyTemplate
{
    public:
        static char const*  m_array[];
}
```

MySpecializedTemplate.h

```
#include <dll_defines.h>
#include <MyTemplate.h>

class MY_API Specialized; //pretend its more than just a decl.

template <> char const* MyTemplate<Specialized>::m_array[] =
{
    "Hello, World", 
    "I need help"
};
```

The issue I am having is when I try and link the DLL in another project, it gives me an error stating:

*definition of dllimport static data member not allowed*

Is there no way to define a static data member of a template and export it
into a DLL??

Comment: What compiler do you use? And why do you define your static data member in the header file?

Comment: I'm using visual studio, so MSVC. Also, templates must be defined in header file from what I understand. I assumed the static data member contained in template class would also need to be. Generally, static data members of classes are initialized in the definition, .cpp file, but I'm not sure what to do for this since its a template.

Comment: Explicit specializations are not templates in fact. So they should be only declared in the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've realized that I can in fact initialize static template variables in an implementation file. I also realized I SHOULD NOT attach an export or import macro to a template function defined in a header file.

```
DONT DO THIS:
template <typename T>
MY_API void foo()
{
    cout << "This won't link, don't try it << endl
}
```

Realized that the above has a pretty bad problem once MY_API is defined as

```
__declspec(dllimport)
```